# My sphere, or scene, disappears when I put in OrbitControls

Tags: three.js

I have a sphere made with three.js

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var width = canvas.offsetWidth,
    height = canvas.offsetHeight;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas,
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio > 1 ? 2 : 1);
renderer.setSize(width, height);
renderer.setClearColor(0x000000,0);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.set(0, 0, 300);

var sphere = new THREE.Group();
scene.add(sphere);
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xfe0e55
});
var linesAmount = 40;
var radius = 50;
var verticesAmount = 900;
for(var j=0;j<linesAmount;j++){
    var index = j;
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    geometry.y = (index/linesAmount) * radius*2;
    for(var i=0;i<=verticesAmount;i++) {
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
        vector.x = Math.cos(i/verticesAmount * Math.PI*2);
        vector.z = Math.sin(i/verticesAmount * Math.PI*2);
        vector._o = vector.clone();
        geometry.vertices.push(vector);
    }
    var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
    sphere.add(line);
}

function updateVertices (a) {
 for(var j=0;j<sphere.children.length;j++){
     var line = sphere.children[j];
     line.geometry.y += 0.1;
     if(line.geometry.y > radius*2) {
         line.geometry.y = 0;
     }
     var radiusHeight = Math.sqrt(line.geometry.y * (2*radius-line.geometry.y));
     for(var i=0;i<=verticesAmount;i++) {
         var vector = line.geometry.vertices[i];
            var ratio = noise.simplex3(vector.x*0.009, vector.z*0.009 + a*0.0006, line.geometry.y*0.009) * 15;
            vector.copy(vector._o);
            vector.multiplyScalar(radiusHeight + ratio);
            vector.y = line.geometry.y - radius;
        }
     line.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
 }
}

function render(a) {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    updateVertices(a);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function onResize() {
    canvas.style.width = '';
    canvas.style.height = '';
    width = canvas.offsetWidth;
    height = canvas.offsetHeight;
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
var resizeTm;
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    resizeTm = clearTimeout(resizeTm);
    resizeTm = setTimeout(onResize, 200);
});
```

/

```
<body class="demo-4">
        <main>
            <div class="content">
                <canvas class="scene scene--full" id="scene"></canvas>
                <div class="content__inner">
                    <h2 class="content__title"></h2>

                    <h3 class="content__subtitle"></h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <script src="/Users/VICSIDIOUS/Desktop/WWW/WWW.VICSIDIOUS.COM/VICSIDIOUS_2018/demo.js"></script>
        <script src="/Users/VICSIDIOUS/Desktop/WWW/WWW.VICSIDIOUS.COM/VICSIDIOUS_2018/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Users/VICSIDIOUS/Desktop/WWW/WWW.VICSIDIOUS.COM/VICSIDIOUS_2018/perlin.js"></script>
        <script src="/Users/VICSIDIOUS/Desktop/WWW/WWW.VICSIDIOUS.COM/VICSIDIOUS_2018/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Users/VICSIDIOUS/Desktop/WWW/WWW.VICSIDIOUS.COM/VICSIDIOUS_2018/demo4.js"></script>
        <script src="/Users/VICSIDIOUS/Desktop/WWW/WWW.VICSIDIOUS.COM/VICSIDIOUS_2018/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    </body>
```

But when I try to add OrbitControls, everything disappears.

- Yes, I am referencing OrbitControl.js
- I've tried using domElement
- I've adjusted the camera like crazy, still no luck

I guess my question is, for anyone experienced with three.js, is there anything in the code that may be conflicting with OrbitControls?

I literally started learning web dev two weeks ago. Please keep that in mind, I'm just looking to learn and doing my best not to ask questions without researching a lot first.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It would be better to provide a live code example (a code snippet, jsfiddle.net, codepen.io)

Comment: I've created a fiddle with most of your code and added `OrbitControls`. Everything seems to work, see https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/6975/.  BTW: In your example code you add an event listener for `mousemove` but did not post the respective function. When using `OrbitControls`, you don't need such a handler at all.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know how to reference the libraries on a fiddle, but seeing Mugen's example I think I understand how to now, sorry!

Mugen, thank you so much! The mouse move listener is for a part of the code that I didn't include that was tweening the sphere in a different way. I guess I should have done away with the EventListener too.

Thanks for taking time and helping me out! 

In your code, when I add the UpdateVertices function, it doesn't work. So I think it must be something related to that function.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, like I said, I am a beginner, so please try not to roll your eyes!

I think I solved it by just calling the OrbitControls script before the line where I called the demo4 (sphere) script in the index file.

**I have a new problem though**: the whole thing is putting a mighty dent on performance. When I run the index page, my whole computer runs slow. It's like the graphics are too heavy?

I will do some research on optimization, I spent all day today trying to understand how the script was constructing the sphere (I took it from a website). I found it interesting that it's actually not rendering a sphere (it's a THREE), it's just rendering and updating lines in a wobbly spherical shape.

Even though the solution was anticlimactic, I learned a lot about three.js trying to solve this problem. Looking forward to see if it can be optimized and made to run smoothly!